# Cocoa2d-x 3.15, How to detect the focus and unfocus event in window

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am developing windows game by using cocos2d-x 3.15 version.

By the way, how to detect the event of focus and unfocus of window?

http://blog.cocos2d-x.org/2017/01/cocos2d-x-v3-14-released/

It says:

```
[NEW] Desktop: add events for window resize, focus and unfocus
```

But I don't find the reference about its usage.

Somebody help me?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out, but take a look at `EventListenerFocus::create()`

Comment: @Acidic, thank you! But I want to know about  focus event of windows, not a scene or node.